# How to remove overlay while drawing polygons on map?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have multiple polygons on map and list of polygons on side menu when i checked a polygon it draws on map. When i checked other polygon it creates other polygon but the issue is when i checked every new polygon its overlays old polygons. I am trying to null polygons before creating new but it's not working. Hope you understand my question.

[image: Ajax Response]

```
 $.ajax({
 url: "{{route('ucs.active')}}",
 method: "POST",
 data: {'id': id, 'is_active': is_active, "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}"},
 success: function (response) {
 let latLong = response.zones;

 let map;
 let polygons = [];
 let driverLat = latLong.map(({
  lat_long
 }) => lat_long)
 let color = latLong.map(({
  color
 }) => color)

 for (let i = 0; i < driverLat.length; i++) {

  let arrayCoords = [];
  let jsonData = JSON.parse(driverLat[i]);
  for (let j = 0; j < jsonData.length; j++) {
    let res = jsonData[j].lat.split(",");
    let lat = parseFloat(res[0]);
    let lng = parseFloat(res[1]);

    arrayCoords.push(new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng));

   }
   if (polygons.length > 0) {
    polygons.setMap(null);
   }

  polygons = new google.maps.Polygon({
    editable: false,
    paths: arrayCoords,
    strokeColor: color[i],
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: color[i],
    fillOpacity: 0.35,
    map: map,
    draggable: false,
    geodesic: true,
  });
}
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: @geocodezip I posted the complete ajax request. I didn't get the solution why it is overlaying on getting new response.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem, you need to provide the value of `response` (or at least a test version that you have proved works)

Comment: @geocodezip I added response in question.

Comment: A picture isn't very useful.  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue (or at least enough information that I can create one that stands a chance of exhibiting the issue).

Comment: @geocodezip I didn't understand what else you need?

Comment: The value of `response` in a format that can be used (not a picture).

Answer (score 0):

When you click on the other check box, you need to set the DrawingMode from google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager class to null, before creating the other polygon.

```
  private _drawingManager: google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager;
  private _drawingOptions: google.maps.drawing.DrawingManagerOptions;

  this._drawingOptions = {
      drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
      drawingControl: false,
      drawingControlOptions: {
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
        drawingModes: [
   
          google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON
        
        ]
      }
    };

    const dm = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager(this._drawingOptions);
    this._drawingManager = dm;
```

You need to set the drawing mode to null on Polygon complete:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(event) {
    if (event.type == google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON) {
        if(polygon != null)
            polygon.setMap(null);
        polygon = event.overlay;
        var bounds = polygon.getBounds();
        drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null);
    }
});
```

Let me know if it helps. Thanks!!

Comment: I am doing it to null as you can see in my question. Where i have to change in my question?

Comment: I edited my answer..You need to add it inside a listener for the OverlayComplete Event.

Comment: Can you edit my question? so i can easily understand.